# htaccess not working 500 internal server error godaddy

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using htaccess for abc.org/dev

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My htaccess is located at **webroot/virtuals/abc.org/dev/.htaccess**

when i hit **abc.org/dev** it redirect me to **abc.org/virtuals/abc.org/dev/**

Is there is something wrong with htaccess?

Please help me.

Comment: This rule is probably somewhere else because I can't see this referral here, try checking the rules with this bad boy: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Answer (score 0):

First you should try this to debug and see if it takes you to Google and if there is no error:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* http://google.com [L]
</IfModule>
```

if it does not take you to Google whatever you type or if still error it means your .htaccess is not taken into consideration!

This also may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687457/mod-rewrite-with-godaddy-hosting